# Coefficients become insignificant by adding additional variable. Explanation?

Tags: regression

I have cross-sectional data where the dependent variable shall be regressed on age. If I include age and age^2 in the regression, coefficients are highly significant. When I add age^3 as well, all coefficients (that of age, age^2, and age^3) become much smaller and insignificant. At this point, I rather expected that if age^3 does not play a role in the model, it is simple insignificant but the coefficients on age and age^2 remain significant.
But this is obviously not the case here. ;) Do you have a reasoning how/why this happens?
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Please search the site before posting a question here. This is a frequently asked question that has been addressed many times.

Comment: They're fighting with each other for pretty much the same share of the market. Plot these powers against each other for your data to see that they are highly correlated.

Comment: Thanks @gung.  Another good candidate for a duplicate is http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/34488.